# Custom allocator bug with STL container

Tags: c++, memory, allocator

I created a custom allocator that allocate memory on construction and release it on destruction. (in order to allow fast allocation/deallocation).
When I use it with STL container, all works fine! Expected when I use the assign method...
I don't understand why...

I've tried to print each pointer allocated /  free, but all looks good.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <stack>
#include <numeric>
#include <list>

template <class T>
class CustomAllocator
{
    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using propagate_on_container_copy_assignment = std::false_type;
        using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::false_type;
        using propagate_on_container_swap = std::false_type;
        using is_always_equal = std::false_type;

        CustomAllocator();
        CustomAllocator(size_type size);
        ~CustomAllocator();

        CustomAllocator(const CustomAllocator&);
        CustomAllocator& operator=(const CustomAllocator&) = delete;
        CustomAllocator(CustomAllocator&& src)
            : m_data(std::move(src.m_data)) , m_free(std::move(src.m_free))
        {
            src.m_data = nullptr;
        }


        CustomAllocator& operator=(CustomAllocator&&) = delete;

        template <class T2>
        CustomAllocator(const CustomAllocator<T2>&);

        template <class T2>
        bool operator==(const CustomAllocator<T2>&) const noexcept;

        template <class T2>
        bool operator!=(const CustomAllocator<T2>&) const noexcept;

        value_type* allocate(size_type);
        void deallocate(value_type* ptr, size_type);

    private:
        template <class>
        friend class CustomAllocator;

        void* m_data = nullptr;
        std::stack<void*> m_free;
};

template <class T>
CustomAllocator<T>::CustomAllocator() : CustomAllocator(1024)
{
}

template <class T>
CustomAllocator<T>::CustomAllocator(size_type size)
{
    m_data = ::operator new(sizeof(T) * size);

    for (auto ptr = static_cast<T*>(m_data) + (size - 1); ptr >= 
         static_cast<T*>(m_data); ptr--)
        m_free.push(ptr);
}

template <class T>
CustomAllocator<T>::CustomAllocator(const CustomAllocator&)
    : CustomAllocator(1024)
{
}

template <class T>
template <class T2>
CustomAllocator<T>::CustomAllocator(const CustomAllocator<T2>&)
    : CustomAllocator(1024)
{
}

template <class T>
CustomAllocator<T>::~CustomAllocator()
{
    if (m_data)
        ::operator delete(m_data);
}

template <class T>
template <class T2>
inline bool CustomAllocator<T>::
operator==(const CustomAllocator<T2>&) const noexcept
{
    return typeid(T) == typeid(T2);
}

template <class T>
template <class T2>
inline bool CustomAllocator<T>::
operator!=(const CustomAllocator<T2>&) const noexcept
{
     return typeid(T) != typeid(T2);
}

template <class T>
typename CustomAllocator<T>::value_type*
CustomAllocator<T>::allocate(size_type size)
{
    if (m_free.empty() || size != 1)
        throw std::bad_alloc();

    auto ptr = m_free.top();

    m_free.pop();

    return reinterpret_cast<value_type*>(ptr);
}

template <class T>
void CustomAllocator<T>::deallocate(value_type* ptr, size_type)
{
    m_free.push(ptr);
}

int main()
{
    std::list<size_t, CustomAllocator<size_t>> containerA;
    std::list<size_t, CustomAllocator<size_t>> containerB;


    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
            containerA.emplace_front();

        // dont works with this
        containerB.assign(10, i);

        containerA.clear();
        containerB.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Actually the program crash.
If I comment 'containerB.assign(10, i);', the program works.
If I replace 'containerB.assign(10, i);' by 'containerB.emplace_front();', the program works.
If I replace 'containerB.assign(10, i);' by 'containerB.insert(containerB.begin(), 10, i);', the program crash. 
I don't understand why...

Error with clang and gcc:
free(): corrupted unsorted chunks
abort (core dumped)

Error with gdb:
free(): corrupted unsorted chunks

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.

UPDATE:

With better operator ==, I have now a SIGSEGV:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555537a in std::__cxx11::_List_base >::_M_clear (this=0x7fffffffdcd0) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/list.tcc:74
74        __cur = __tmp->_M_next;

The valgrind output:

```
==17407== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17407== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17407== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17407== Command: ./a.out
==17407== 
==17407== Invalid read of size 8
==17407==    at 0x10937A: std::__cxx11::_List_base<unsigned long, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> >::_M_clear() (list.tcc:74)
==17407==    by 0x109287: std::__cxx11::list<unsigned long, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> >::clear() (stl_list.h:1507)
==17407==    by 0x108F0C: main (bug.cpp:154)
==17407==  Address 0x5b93b00 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24,576 free'd
==17407==    at 0x4C3123B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17407==    by 0x1091CE: CustomAllocator<std::_List_node<unsigned long> >::~CustomAllocator() (bug.cpp:100)
==17407==    by 0x109107: std::__cxx11::_List_base<unsigned long, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> >::_List_impl::~_List_impl() (stl_list.h:382)
==17407==    by 0x109205: std::__cxx11::_List_base<unsigned long, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> >::~_List_base() (stl_list.h:506)
==17407==    by 0x10915B: std::__cxx11::list<unsigned long, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> >::~list() (stl_list.h:834)
==17407==    by 0x109B66: std::__cxx11::list<unsigned long, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> >::insert(std::_List_const_iterator<unsigned long>, unsigned long, unsigned long const&) (list.tcc:122)
==17407==    by 0x109586: std::__cxx11::list<unsigned long, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> >::_M_fill_assign(unsigned long, unsigned long const&) (list.tcc:300)
==17407==    by 0x10926C: std::__cxx11::list<unsigned long, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> >::assign(unsigned long, unsigned long const&) (stl_list.h:897)
==17407==    by 0x108EEE: main (bug.cpp:151)
==17407==  Block was alloc'd at
==17407==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17407==    by 0x109665: CustomAllocator<std::_List_node<unsigned long> >::CustomAllocator(unsigned long) (bug.cpp:76)
==17407==    by 0x10A3B6: CustomAllocator<std::_List_node<unsigned long> >::CustomAllocator<unsigned long>(CustomAllocator<unsigned long> const&) (bug.cpp:92)
==17407==    by 0x109FFE: std::__cxx11::list<unsigned long, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> >::list(unsigned long, unsigned long const&, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> const&) (stl_list.h:717)
==17407==    by 0x109B0B: std::__cxx11::list<unsigned long, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> >::insert(std::_List_const_iterator<unsigned long>, unsigned long, unsigned long const&) (list.tcc:122)
==17407==    by 0x109586: std::__cxx11::list<unsigned long, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> >::_M_fill_assign(unsigned long, unsigned long const&) (list.tcc:300)
==17407==    by 0x10926C: std::__cxx11::list<unsigned long, CustomAllocator<unsigned long> >::assign(unsigned long, unsigned long const&) (stl_list.h:897)
==17407==    by 0x108EEE: main (bug.cpp:151)
==17407== 
==17407== 
==17407== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17407==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17407==   total heap usage: 504 allocs, 504 frees, 668,800 bytes allocated
==17407== 
==17407== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==17407== 
==17407== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17407== ERROR SUMMARY: 100 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Crash as in? throwing an exception?

Comment: Fyi,  `void` for `T` in your `size_t` argument constructor results in at-best-hopeful behavior. This same problems happens elsewhere as well. I'm frankly shocked your compiler doesn't spew warnings (which should be treated as errors) at you, as mine certainly does.

Comment: I've replaced the for by :     for (auto ptr = static_cast<T*>(m_data) + (size - 1); ptr >= static_cast<T*>(m_data); ptr--)
        m_free.push(ptr);
But dont works.

Comment: The program crash: SIGABRT

Comment: Have you tried debugging, for example to see how your allocate and deallocate functions are actually called? Or running under a tool like valgrind?

Comment: valgrind detect no leaks, and gdb result is:
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51 ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.

I have added some print in each method / constructor / destructor, the program dont crash inside allocator function.

Answer (score 0):

`m_data` is a pointer to `void`. There is pointer arithmetic performed on `m_data` in the constructor of `CustomAllocator` in the following line.

```
for (auto ptr = m_data + (sizeof(T) * (size - 1)); ptr >= m_data; ptr -= sizeof(T))
```

As per the standard, pointer arithmetic on `void*` is ill-formed. This could be leading to undefined behavior.

**EDIT**
The OP has been updated and there is no more pointer arithmetic performed on a `void*`. So we have to find other causes for the crash.
For `list`  container `emplace_front` does not affect the validity of iterators and references. But both `assign` and `clear` invalidates all references, pointers and iterators referring to the elements of the container.
So the program works with `emplace_front` and crashes with `assign`.

Comment: @dj4567: Edited the answer accordingly providing a possible reason for the crash.

Comment: Yes, I've read. The assign is always performed on an empty container, since for each loop the containerB is cleared. So I don't understand why :/
The code is simple and I've spent many time to debug this... Its weird.

when I call the assign method, the code call the allocator constructor, I found this weird. Why the assign method create new allocator? :O

Comment: If I replace 'containerB.assign(10, i);' by 'containerB.insert(containerB.begin(), 10, i);', it dont works. So the problem dont come from iterator or reference invalidated, since insert method dont invalidate iterator & reference.

Comment: @dj4567: It looks as if there are more problems in your code. I tried to debug and found that the destructors were called even before the `for` loops were executed. See this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ISFklTE5ut8PqwiC. And they are called later as well.

Comment: Yes, Because std::list create a new allocator in order to transform CustomAllocator<size_t> to CustomAllocator<td::_List_node<long unsigned int>>.
So we have some copy constructor and move constructor called.
I've updated my code, now I've a segmentation fault instead of a SIGABRT.
I suppose that std::list dont like iterator that is always not equal, so I've updated the operator==.
I dont see any things weird in my code... I dont understand :(

Comment: Now, In the updated code, if I comment the ::operator delete in the destructor , all works. Otherwise I obtain a SIGSEGV... Its very weird!

Comment: look this: the deallocate method is called with a weird ptr:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/ySGO6nbdPn6RyjPk

What do you think about this?
Perhaps: The allocator compare equal, so the list use an allocator to deallocate a pointer allocated with the other allocator. Later, the allocator is deleted so the other allocator have dangling pointer?
Conclusion: The pool allocator dont works with stl?
I don't know... If you have a better idea....

Comment: Look also this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZwsM8PihICRofs9s
I have no idea how to fix this :O

Answer (score 0):

Allocators since C++11 can have state.

But allocators copied from the same allocator share state, so that something allocated by original allocator should deallocate fine with copy.

Also operator== and operator!= should compare the state, allocators should not be equal if the state is different.

This can be implemented by having a pointer to potentially shared pool in your allocator rather than directly having pool in allocator. (Shared allocator's pool is sometimes called 'arena').

Before C++11, allocators could not have state at all. So that objects can be allocated/deallocated even with default-constructed allocator, which may be different instance each time. In this case your equality operators are correct, but you need to have one global pool, rather than possibility for separate pool for each container.

Comment: I can put the void* and stack into a struct and manage a pointer on this struct?

Comment: yes, as long as different copies of the same allocator would access the same struct.

Comment: But an allocator<T> that use the copy allocator of allocator<T2> will not share the same struct. right?

Comment: Yes, allocators for different types may have not shared struct, since structure allocated by allocator<T> will be freed by some allocator<T>, but not by allocator<T2>.  However, they may share the struct as well.

Comment: In this case I need to have a sort of global map that contains each Pool for each Type... But since multiple allocator of T will use the same pool T, I have 2 options:
1/ Add a mutex in the shared pool, but in this case the efficiency of the pool is lost... so the pool become useless.
2/ Keep non thread safe, but in this case I can't use multiple Allocator<T> in a multithread context.

Right? Do you have a better idea?

Comment: If your compiler/STL are C++11 compliant, then allocator may have state.
So, two instances of allocator<T> must have the same pool only if one is a copy of another (or one was assigned to another).
Otherwise, two instances of allocator<T> may have different pools.

So, you only need to make sure that copy of allocator<T> copies pointer to pool (which may be achieved even with default copy constructor).

Comment: Before C++11 you would really need to use pool per type.

Comment: And if you have C++17, you don't even need to implement your own allocator. You just implement your pool by inheriting `std::pmr::memory_resource` and pass it to containers that would use `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator`. Containers with that allocator are available in std::pmr namespace.

Comment: I'm using C++17, and I know the memory_resource. But I have an issue with the memory resource.
Currently I have a pool of object (for example a pool of size_t, a pool of char).
I would like to use a memory_resource but I can't.
The copy constructor of std::polymorphic_allocator (used with std::memory_resource) do:
Constructs a polymorphic_allocator using other.resource() as the underlying memory resource.
In this case I can't have a pool like this. In order to used the memory_resource, the memory_resource can allow all size (my current pool can only allocate the size of a type).

Comment: A polymorphic_allocator<T> will use the same memory_resource if copied from polymorphic_allocator<T2>. So my current pool can't work with this system. Right?

Comment: Yes.
Then you should not use memory_resource.
Actually, I've figured out, that it was misleading to say "This can be implemented by having a pointer to potentially shared pool in your allocator rather than directly having pool in allocator". Yes, it is commonly done, but you are not obliged to do so. As you have defined `propagate_on_container_*` traits to false_type, you may have pool directly in allocator. 
Still, you'll need to fix == and != opreators, they should be equal only if instance is equal, not typeid.

Answer (score 0):

After this discussion, I have implemented a statefull alloator, but I have issue with std::list.
I posted a question about that: [STL container don't support statefull allocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148198/stl-container-dont-support-statefull-allocator)